# Batteries for solar application, why C10 only?

Tags: batteries, solar-cell

Some Solar PV system integrators in India are insisting on using C10 batteries only, which they have named solar batteries.  In my view the selection of battery depends on charging source , environmental condition and discharge requirement.  That is why I have posed the question as why we need C10 batteries for Solar, or is it mandatory?

Comment: Huh?  What is a "C10" or "C20" battery?  That is not a standard designation.

Answer (score 2):

The C-Rating has to do with how fast you can discharge the battery.  C10 means that you will get the rated Ampere hour capacity if you discharge the battery completely in 10 hours.

[This site](http://solarhomestead.com/battery-amp-hour-ratings/) has an explanation of the C-rating system and what it means.  In short, the faster you discharge a battery (the higher the load is that you put on it) the less energy you will get out of it.  Take a battery rated for 100Ah C10.  If you put a load on it such that is discharged to its limit in 10 hours (10 Amps for 10 hours,) you will get the rated 100Ah out of it.  If you put a smaller load on it (say, 5 Amperes,) then you will get more energy out of it (perhaps 120Ah.)  The exact relationship between C rating and actual discharged energy depends on the battery chemistry and structure.

You use the C-Rating to match your battery to your expected load.  A 100Ah battery rated C40 wouldn't be much good if you need to draw 10 Amps for 10 hours - it won't deliver that much energy that fast.

Presumably you would want to use  C10 instead of a C20 because it can deliver more of its energy in a short time - it is better for heavy loads.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen Cx refers to the capacity of a battery. You can use any capacity of battery you wish for a solar application. You have a number of things to think about including: maximum charging current, environment - the temperature.  If it's a solar application does that mean the battery will be situated outside and subject to low temperatures?  Often the charging current or voltage needs to be reduced for low temperatures (temperature compensation).

There are also a type of lead acid battery often better suited to solar applications called a solar battery" which can be discharged to a lower level than conventional lead acid batteries.    And if you're dealing with lead-acid batteries then you need to understand the difference between a leisure battery and car battery. Both are lead acid and differ in design.  A car battery is designed to give a very high current (hundreds of amps) for a few seconds and is not particularly well suited to being used (having a current drain) for a long period of time.

A leisure battery is designed to be charged fully, current drawn from it for days continously, drained and then recharged fully. Its plates inside are thicker and designed for this kind of use.

So if you wanted to charge a battery up, and use that battery for powering a television in say a caravan, mobile home, then you would go for a leisure battery or solar battery.

Keep the car batteries for driving the starter motor in the car only.

I'm not going to write a definitive article on batteries and how you charge them. But this should give you a starting point.

But it sounds as if you need to do some research into the capacity (ah) of a battery and what it means?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.  I understand the AH, but the system integrator insists on putting C10 batteries only (obviously discharge performance).  Eg:  Instead of 100 Ah/ C10, what if I use 100Ah/C20?   what is the unique feature of solar battery?  What are the major performance or service life factors of the C10 rating battery?  little confused to some market feedback

Comment: Can you point me at a link for these C10 batteries?

Comment: http://upsinverterinfo.com/exide-solar-tubular-battery-pros-and-cons.html    My question is the discharge current depends on load and will it make any difference if I discharge 100ah battery at 10 amps/ hour irrespective of C10 OR C20 mentioned?

Comment: Yes, it matters. Discharging a 100 Ah battery at 10 amps is the definition of C10 - 100 Ah divided by 10 amps. If you use a C20 in these circumstances, you are pulling more current than it is designed to give, and will probably reduce its service life.

Answer (score 1):

If a battery has a capacity, \$ C \$, of 100 ampere-hours at a discharge rate of \$\frac{C}{10}\$, that means that if

you take \$\frac{C}{10H} = \frac{100AH}{10H} = 10A\$ out of the battery continuously, its voltage will remain above the

charge point for \$ t = \frac{100AH}{10A} = 10\$ hours.

If you took more than 10A from the battery its capacity would decrease to less than 100AH, while if you took less than 10A, its capacity would increase to more than 100AH.

If you had a battery with a capacity of 100AH at a discharge rate of \$\frac{C}{20}\$, then the battery's capacity would allow its charge to last for 20 hours with 5A out of it continuously.

It seems to me that what your boss wants to do is to make sure he gets the maximum discharge time from the battery, which will happen - for the same load current and capacity - if the rate of

discharge is \$\frac{C}{10}\$ instead of \$\frac{C}{20}\$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the doubts.  But why only c10 is suggested for Solar applications

Comment: @rocky: It's not c10, it's ' \$\frac{C}{10}\$ ' and it's because, for identical insolation and load profiles, the \$\frac{C}{10}\$ battery will deliver more energy between charges than will a \$\frac{C}{20}\$.